# getting `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` when exporting data to csv

Tags: node.js, csv, stream

I'm trying to convert data to csv and send it to client to download it, but i'm getting the error i indicated in the title.

I'm using node js stream because i'm dealing with a big data.

Above, you will find my code.

```
router.get('/backoffice/moderateur/organismes/export/:status', checkAuth, checkProfile('moderateur'), tryAndCatch(async (req, res) => {

    let codeRegion = req.user.codeRegion;
    let { status } = await Joi.validate(req.params, {
        status: Joi.string().allow(['all', 'active', 'inactive']).default('all'),
    }, { abortEarly: false });

    let stream = await db.collection('accounts').find({
        profile: 'organisme',
        codeRegion: codeRegion,
        ...(status === 'all' ? {} : { passwordHash: { $exists: status === 'active' } }),
    }).stream();

    // const organismes = await db.collection('accounts').find({
    //     profile: 'organisme',
    //     codeRegion: codeRegion,
    //     ...(status === 'all' ? {} : { passwordHash: { $exists: status === 'active' } }),
    // }).toArray();

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=avis.csv');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1');
    let lines = 'SIRET;EMAIL;NOM\n'
    res.write(lines);

     // organismes.forEach(organisme => {
     //    lines += organisme.SIRET + ';' +
     //        organisme.courriel + ';' +
     //        comment.courriel + '\n';
     // });

     let handleError = e => {
         logger.error('An error occurred', e);
         res.status(500);
         stream.push(Boom.boomify(e).output.payload);
     };

     stream
     .on('error', handleError)
     .pipe(transformObject(async organisme => {
       return organisme.SIRET + ';' +
          organisme.raisonSociale + ';' +
          organisme.courriel + '\n';
     }))
     .pipe(encodeStream('UTF-16BE'))
     .pipe(res);

     // res.send(organismes);

}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified on which line you are getting this error.

However, from looking at the code my best guess is that you're triggering `handleError` which tries to do `res.status(500)` this will trigger exception as you've already sent headers implicitly here `res.write(lines)`.

Answer (score 0):

i had to add this at the end :

```
.on('end', () => res.end());
```